# Find nth week recurrence on week days with moment js

Tags: javascript, date, time, calendar, momentjs

I have just started moment js, I'm trying to generate recurrence for every nth week for defined week days

I have tried this code so far but not getting True for defined week days

```
// Create a date to start from
let date = moment(new Date("05-12-2022"));

let rInterval = moment(date).recur().every(["Saturday"]).daysOfWeek().every(2).week();

console.log(rInterval.matches(new Date("05-21-2022"))) //saturday at 21 may

output: false
```

but as of now that `week()` function matches exactly 2 week

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
`TRUE`

This should match `Saturday` in every 2 weeks from the start date

Comment: `moment(new Date("05-12-2022"))` is not a good idea. One of the primary uses of moment.js is to parse timestamps, but that expression uses the built–in parser and will likely return either an invalid date or perhaps 5 December or 12 May. Use `moment('05-12-2022', 'MM-DD-YYYY')`

Comment: I tried `moment('05-12-2022', 'MM-DD-YYYY')` now it is not giving an error but still getting `false`

Comment: I got It! `moment('05-14-2022', 'MM-DD-YYYY').recur().every(2).day().every([5]).daysOfWeek();` Now it is recurring for every 2 week on `Saturday` from start date.

Comment: Then post an answer and accept it. :-)

Comment: Okay, answer added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This will work perfectly**

`moment('05-14-2022', 'MM-DD-YYYY').recur().every(2).day().every([5]).daysOfWeek();`

Now it is recurring for every **2 weeks** on **Saturday** from the start date.